# How to access a int pointer as 2D array using macros in C?

Tags: c

if R is my rows number and C my column number
I initialize a pointer like this:

`int * a = (int*) malloc(R*C*sizeof(int));`

Then to access the second element in the second row I type:

`a[1*c + 1]`

I want to emulate a 2D arr.

How can I make a macro that will convert this: `a[i][j]` to this `a[i*c + j]`?

Comment: Why not use a 2D array, but an unsafe hack instead?

Comment: Macros take comma separated arguments, they can't do general syntax conversion

Comment: Use this `#define a(i,j) a[(i)*c+(j)]` but I don't think it will be useful using the original one is much more safer and readable

Comment: @Sabrina so what about `a(1+3, 4)`

Comment: @Sabrina and where would `c` come from? You hopefully don't recommend using global variables or relying on a corresponding local variable for a macro?

Comment: @Olaf OP here needs to take care of the placement of macro. `c` could be a macro also.

Comment: @Sabrina: That's are bad as relying on a global variable (and effectively the same problem). That's bad practice and would not pass a serious code-audit.

Comment: The question in itself makes non sense to me.

Comment: There is no `c`.  Don't forget it is a column which is simply a full row, i.e. - `a[(i)*(((i)+1)+(j))]`

Comment: Big time mis-read, sorry

Comment: The `c` would need to be the same `C` used to allocate memory, being a case sensitive language.

Comment: If VLA pointers are supported (which is the case for modern C compilers), then use `int (*a)[C] = malloc(R*C*sizeof(int));`, so you won't need any macro.

Answer (score 2):

A macro can't read and convert square brackets.  But you can write:

```
int (*b)[C] = (void *)a;
```

and then you can use `b[i][j]` which has the same meaning as `a[i*C + j]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a separate macro for every dynamic array that you might use, you will need something a bit more general. For example:

```
#define INDEX_2D(array, i, j, j_sz) array[ (i) * (j_sz) + (j) ]
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
INDEX_2D(my_array, row, col, C) = x;
printf("%d\n", INDEX_2D(my_array, row, col, C));
```

Still, this seems clumsy. If you can't use actual 2d arrays, why not just use straightforward indexing calculations, which actually seem more clear?

```
my_array[row * C + col] = x;
printf("%d\n", my_array[row * C + col]);
```

Comment: The last suggestion is best. Indexing the array directly is shorter than the macro version, only 1 effective character more than the 2D equivalent `my_array[row][col]` but above all it is clear and easy to read. As with a newbie function that adds or compares two integers, the macro is only of use until you become accustomed to taking the inline syntax in your stride.

Comment: @WeatherVane-- agreed. I hope my answer did not come across as suggesting that using a macro is in any way a good idea for this. I had hoped that it would instead illustrate the clumsy nature of a general macro solution here.

Comment: No, the answer led to that conclusion, having offered a solution, hence my UV.

Answer (score 0):

The preprocessor is not a good tool for faking 2D array access on a 1D array.  Another approach would be to create an array of pointers into the 1D array, like so:

```
int *a = malloc( R * C * sizeof *a ); // do not cast the result of malloc!
int *b[] = { &a[0], &a[C], &a[2*C], ..., &a[(R-1) * C] };
```

The result is something like the following (assume `R == 2` and `C == 3`):

```
   +---+                +---+
b: |   | b[0] -----> a: |   | a[0]
   +---+                +---+
   |   | b[1] ---+      |   | a[1]
   +---+         |      +---+
                 |      |   | a[2]
                 |      +---+
                 +----> |   | a[3]
                        +---+
                        |   | a[4]
                        +---+
                        |   | a[5]
                        +---+
```

This way, you can use `b[i][j]` to access elements in `a` (`b[i][j] == a[i * R + j]`).